# Typescript: Is it possible to pass object type as parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a component `Grid` which is re-used in many different parts of the project.
This `Grid` has a configurable columns and a number of functions.
So in my project, I will have `Grid-A`, `Grid-B`, `Grid-C` and so on which will use `Grid`.

The codes in each of `Grid-A`, `Grid-B` and so on are quite similar, only the difference is the object type that the grid uses.

For example, in `Grid-A` component, I will have the following constructor

```
constructor(private excelService: ExcelService, private commonService: CommonService, private gridAService: GridAService) { }

onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* some code */
    const header: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new GridAExcel());
}

initialiseGrid(data: GridADto) {
    /* some code */
}
```

in `Grid-B`, I will have

```
constructor(private excelService: ExcelService, private commonService: CommonService, private gridBService: GridBService) { }

onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* some code */
    const header: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new GridBExcel());
}

initialiseGrid(data: GridBDto) {
    /* some code */
}
```

Since the functions are the same, but it has different parameter types (`GridAService` vs `GridBService`, `GridAExcel` vs `GridBExcel`, `GridADto` vs `GridBDto`), I want to create another component to bridge between `Grid` and `Grid-A`/`Grid-B`, name it `Project-Grid`.

So instead of `Grid-A` using `Grid`, it will use `Project-Grid`, and `Project-Grid` will use `Grid`. In this `Project-Grid`, it should accept a dynamic parameter type, and `Grid-A` will pass `GridAService`, `GridAExcel`, `GridADto` to `Project-Grid`.

Is it possible to do this in Typescript? If not, what is the best way to achieve similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, the answers is [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)!

```js
class ProjectGrid<GridService, GridExcel, GridDto> {
  constructor(
    private excelService: ExcelService,
    private commonService: CommonService,
    private gridService: GridService,
  ) { }
}
```

But be aware that all these generic parameters exist only in compile-time, and you can't do something like `new GridExcel()` in your functions; you will need to pass *something* into constructor and save it in some field; the *something* may be a class itself, or a fabric function that creates objects of this class:

```js
class ProjectGrid<GridService, GridExcel, GridDto> {
  constructor(
    private excelService: ExcelService,
    private commonService: CommonService,
    private gridService: GridService,
    private gridExcelFabric: () => GridExcel,
  ) { }

  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* some code */
    const header = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.gridExcelFabric());
  }
}
```

Another caveat is that you may actually need your type parameters (like `GridService`) to be not just any arbitrary types, but share some common properties and methods. If you have a type describing this common functionality (let's say, `GridServiceBase`), you can do this:

```js
class ProjectGrid<GridService extends GridServiceBase> {}
```

After that, you can assume that all objects of type `GridService` are also of type `GridServiceBase`, and you can use `GridServiceBase`'s methods and properties.